# Cannot start nexus: Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor

Tags: java, jetty, nexus

I'm currently working on configuring nexus on our server. I followed all the required steps steps but it seems that I'm missing something.

java version "1.8.0_121"

nexus version "3.2.1"

My complete log trace is below:

```
              jvm 1    | Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1) Error injecting: org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus
              jvm 1    |   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
              jvm 1    |   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
              jvm 1    |   while locating org.sonatype.nexus.Nexus
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1 error
              jvm 1    |       role: org.sonatype.nexus.Nexus
              jvm 1    |   roleHint:
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:238)
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:226)
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:220)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener.contextInitialized(NexusBooterListener.java:43)
              jvm 1    |    ... 41 more
              jvm 1    | Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1) Error injecting: org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus
              jvm 1    |   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
              jvm 1    |   at ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
              jvm 1    |   while locating org.sonatype.nexus.Nexus
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1 error
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:952)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.locators.QualifiedBean.getValue(QualifiedBean.java:85)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.locators.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:55)
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:234)
              jvm 1    |    ... 44 more
              jvm 1    | Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1) Error starting: class org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus
              jvm 1    |   while locating org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus
              jvm 1    |
              jvm 1    | 1 error
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:952)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:978)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.guice.bean.reflect.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:996)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.Scopes$1$1.get(Scopes.java:63)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:40)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:943)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:996)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:939)
              jvm 1    |    ... 47 more
              jvm 1    | Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.personality.plexus.lifecycle.phase.StartingException: Could not start Nexus!
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus.start(DefaultNexus.java:651)
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.start(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:229)
              jvm 1    |    at org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusLifecycleManager.manage(PlexusLifecycleManager.java:145)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.guice.plexus.binders.PlexusBeanBinder.afterInjection(PlexusBeanBinder.java:79)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.MembersInjectorImpl.notifyListeners(MembersInjectorImpl.java:97)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:95)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:253)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:943)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:996)
              jvm 1    |    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:939)
              jvm 1    |    ... 58 more
              jvm 1    | Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor : Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor
              jvm 1    | ---- Debugging information ----
              jvm 1    | message             : Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor
              jvm 1    | cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException
              jvm 1    | cause-message       : Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor
              jvm 1    | class               : org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.CRepository
              jvm 1    | required-type       : org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom
              jvm 1    | path                : /org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.CRepository/externalConfiguration
              jvm 1    | line number         : 29
              jvm 1    | -------------------------------
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:89)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:76)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:246)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doUnmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:218)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:162)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:82)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceUnmarshaller.java:63)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:76)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convertAnother(TreeUnmarshaller.java:60)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.start(TreeUnmarshaller.java:137)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.unmarshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:33)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:923)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.unmarshal(XStream.java:909)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:853)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.fromXML(XStream.java:845)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.AbstractRevertableConfiguration.copyObject(AbstractRevertableConfiguration.java:85)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.AbstractRevertableConfiguration.getConfiguration(AbstractRevertableConfiguration.java:28)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.model.CRepositoryCoreConfiguration.getConfiguration(CRepositoryCoreConfiguration.java:39)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.ConfigurableRepository.getCurrentConfiguration(ConfigurableRepository.java:25)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.proxy.repository.ConfigurableRepository.getCurrentConfiguration(ConfigurableRepository.java:17)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.AbstractConfigurable.configure(AbstractConfigurable.java:153)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.runtime.DefaultApplicationRuntimeConfigurationBuilder.createRepositoryFromModel(DefaultApplicationRuntimeConfigurationBuilder.java:46)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration.instantiateRepository(DefaultNexusConfiguration.java:506)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration.createRepositories(DefaultNexusConfiguration.java:472)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.configuration.application.DefaultNexusConfiguration.createInternals(DefaultNexusConfiguration.java:454)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus.startService(DefaultNexus.java:685)
              jvm 1    |    at org.sonatype.nexus.DefaultNexus.start(DefaultNexus.java:647)
              jvm 1    |    ... 67 more
              jvm 1    | Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ObjectAccessException: Cannot construct org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.Xpp3Dom as it does not have a no-args constructor
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.newInstance(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:71)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.instantiateNewInstance(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:308)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.unmarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:161)
              jvm 1    |    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeUnmarshaller.convert(TreeUnmarshaller.java:82)
              jvm 1    |    ... 94 more
              jvm 1    | 2017-07-06 13:29:19 INFO  [er_start_runner] - org.mortbay.log               - Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8081
```

Comment: You should accept @rseddon's answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That stack trace is not coming from Nexus 3.x, none of the classes in the stack exist in that version.

It's coming from Nexus 1.x or 2.x, and it looks like you've starting a pretty old version, since you seem to be hitting this:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-4453

Comment: Excellent reference. So the solution is to switch back to Java 6, temporarily.